# Alternatives to multisim

Tags: microcontroller

Could someone tell me alternatives to multisim for simulating pic
microcontrollers.

Free alternatives , not just the free demo version of Proteus.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Microchip's MPLAB IDE comes with a simulator.

Answer (score 0):

PICsim - PIC microcontroller simulator.
XCSIM and XCASM are available as integral PIC components of the ZMech CASE tool.
PIC SIMULATOR IDE. 
MATLAB IDE.
MiSim DE.
These are the various simulators for PIC micro-controller and among those
MATLAB is most preferable.